# Compiling Application with libprotobuf, Conflicting declaration of Functions

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am attempting to compile a simple application on linux, linking it with Protocol Buffers library. I get the following error during compilation:

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:176,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:394,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/cstdlib:75,
                 from /home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.79.0-amd64/include/boost/config/platform/linux.hpp:15,
                 from /home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.79.0-amd64/include/boost/config.hpp:57,
                 from /home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.79.0-amd64/include/boost/program_options/config.hpp:10,
                 from /home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.79.0-amd64/include/boost/program_options/options_description.hpp:11,
                 from /home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.79.0-amd64/include/boost/program_options.hpp:15,
                 from /home/bdn/Programming/Beaglebone/source/software/appconfig.hpp:15,
                 from /home/bdn/Programming/Beaglebone/source/software/appconfig.cpp:12:
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:98:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint32_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::FromHost(uint32_t)’
   98 | inline uint32_t FromHost(uint32_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:90:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint16_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::FromHost(uint16_t)’
   90 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:106:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint64_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::FromHost(uint64_t)’
  106 | inline uint64_t FromHost(uint64_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:98:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint32_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::FromHost(uint32_t)’
   98 | inline uint32_t FromHost(uint32_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:106:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint64_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::FromHost(uint64_t)’
  106 | inline uint64_t FromHost(uint64_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:90:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint16_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::FromHost(uint16_t)’
   90 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:122:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint32_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::ToHost(uint32_t)’
  122 | inline uint32_t ToHost(uint32_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:114:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint16_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::ToHost(uint16_t)’
  114 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:130:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint64_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::ToHost(uint64_t)’
  130 | inline uint64_t ToHost(uint64_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:122:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint32_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::ToHost(uint32_t)’
  122 | inline uint32_t ToHost(uint32_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:130:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint64_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::ToHost(uint64_t)’
  130 | inline uint64_t ToHost(uint64_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:114:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint16_t google::protobuf::internal::little_endian::ToHost(uint16_t)’
  114 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:150:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint32_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::FromHost(uint32_t)’
  150 | inline uint32_t FromHost(uint32_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:142:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint16_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::FromHost(uint16_t)’
  142 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:158:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint64_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::FromHost(uint64_t)’
  158 | inline uint64_t FromHost(uint64_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:150:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint32_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::FromHost(uint32_t)’
  150 | inline uint32_t FromHost(uint32_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:158:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint64_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::FromHost(uint64_t)’
  158 | inline uint64_t FromHost(uint64_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:142:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint16_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::FromHost(uint16_t)’
  142 | inline uint16_t FromHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:174:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint32_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::ToHost(uint32_t)’
  174 | inline uint32_t ToHost(uint32_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:166:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint16_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::ToHost(uint16_t)’
  166 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:182:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint64_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::ToHost(uint64_t)’
  182 | inline uint64_t ToHost(uint64_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:174:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint32_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::ToHost(uint32_t)’
  174 | inline uint32_t ToHost(uint32_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:182:17: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘uint64_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::ToHost(uint64_t)’
  182 | inline uint64_t ToHost(uint64_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
/home/bdn/Programming/protobuf_amd64/include/google/protobuf/endian.h:166:17: note: previous declaration ‘uint16_t google::protobuf::internal::big_endian::ToHost(uint16_t)’
  166 | inline uint16_t ToHost(uint16_t value) {
      |                 ^~~~~~
make[2]: *** [source/software/CMakeFiles/xmbedSw.dir/build.make:76: source/software/CMakeFiles/xmbedSw.dir/appconfig.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:283: source/software/CMakeFiles/xmbedSw.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

The functions appear to be in 2 separate namespaces within the endian.h file. This file is apart of the PB headers.
Is there a flag somewhere I need to set to get past this?
Do I need to rebuild librotobuf?
I am using protoc version 3.21.2 with GNU C and CXX compilers at 9.4.0.

Comment: *"conflicting declaration of C function"*  Seems like the compiler belives this to be C. And C functions can of course not be overloaded.

Comment: You have probably run into a naming collision between two functions thanks to an ill-advised and overly broad `using namespace` statement. We can confirm this with a [mre]. Without the [mre] we can only guess.

Comment: @user4581301, This was a mix of C++ and C, but I did remove "C" from the LANGUAGES setting in the top-level CMakeList file and recompile. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out a simple CMakeLists file variable being misspelled was the root cause 'sources' vs 'source'. The error cause here created cascading errors leading to the above error, from the looks of it.

Comment: Hello @xBACP. How did you solve?

Comment: @ViniCoder, I misspelled a custom CMake variable as stated. Spelling it correctly solved the issue.